# Is the following function absolutely continuous?.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

For a fixed $x\in\Omega$ is the function $F(x,y)=min\{1,\frac{\delta_{\Omega}(x)\delta_{\Omega}(y)}{|x-y|^2}\}$ - where $\delta_{\Omega}(x)$, $\delta_{\Omega}(y)$ are the distances from $x$, $y$ to the boundary $\partial\Omega$ - an absolutely continuous function?. Here $\Omega$ is a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Assuming that $\partial\Omega$ is smooth.

Comment: It seems to me that this function is Lipschitz. Where do you got this problem?

Comment: Thank you very much. I was working with the Green's function of a Laplacian when I came across this particular function. It is not from any text book. Can you please give me a proof of this function being Lipshitz?. If it is Lipshitz then it obviously is absolutely continuous.

Comment: I am trying to write a proof. The idea I am trying to use, is that near $x$, your function is $1$ and so it is Lipschitz. Far from $x$ your function is also Lipschitz, because the funtcion $|x-y|^2$ is bounded if $y$ is far from $x$ and the distance function is Lipschitz.

Comment: Yes thats right. Close to $x$, say inn a neighbourhood of $x$, $\lambda=1$. Note that on the boundary $\partial\Omega$, $\lambda=0$. All we need to figure out is in the rest of the region is how the function is Lipshitz?...Thanks for the attempt Tom$\acute{a}$s.